# How to Concatenate 2 Embedding layers with 'mask_zero=True' in Keras2.0？

Tags: python, keras, embedding, masking

I have two Embedding layers, one assigned `mask_zero=True`, the other not, as defined bellow.

```
a = Input(shape=[30])
b = Input(shape=[30])
emb_a = Embedding(10, 5, mask_zero=True)(a)
emb_b = Embedding(20, 5, mask_zero=False)(b)
cat = Concatenate(axis=1)([emb_a, emb_b]) # problem here
model = Model(inputs=[a, b], outputs=[cat])
```

When I tried to concatenate them at `axis=1`, I expected an output with size `[None, 60, 5]`, but it raised an error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 5.
Shapes are [1] and [5]. for 'concatenate_1/concat_1' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: 
[?,30,1], [?,30,5], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.
```

Why the shape of `emb_a` become `[None, 30, 1]`？Why there is another empty tensor `[]` fed into Concatenate?

If the two Embedding layers are both assigned `mask_zero=True` or both `mask_zero=False`, it would not raise this error. 
If they are concatenated at `axis=2`，it would not raise this error either.

My keras version is 2.0.8.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `mask_zero=True` in one case and `mask_zero=False` in another its causing some issue internally (which should not be happening), Maybe it's a bug and you can report it on Github.

For now 2 options that I think worked is using only one of these for both the embeddings: `mask_zero=True` or `mask_zero=False`

```
a = Input(shape=[30])
b = Input(shape=[30])
emb_a = Embedding(10, 5)(a)
emb_b = Embedding(20, 5)(b)
cat = Concatenate(axis=1)([emb_a, emb_b])
model = Model(inputs=[a, b], outputs=[cat])

print(model.output_shape) # (None, 60, 5)
```

Another approach to solve this problem is to concatenate on `axis=-1`

```
a = Input(shape=[30])
b = Input(shape=[30])
emb_a = Embedding(10, 5, mask_zero=True)(a)
emb_b = Embedding(20, 5, mask_zero=False)(b)
cat = Concatenate()([emb_a, emb_b]) # problem here
model = Model(inputs=[a, b], outputs=[cat])

print(model.output_shape) # (None, 30, 10)
```

Comment: I really need concatenating the two embeddings at axis=1, since input  `a` and `b` might have different words (e.g. `a` 15 words and `b` 30 words), while embedding 5 is remained. I want to concatenate `(None, 15, 5)` and `(None, 30, 5)` into `(None, 45, 5)`.

Comment: @GeraltXu I looked into it more, Think there is a bug in Keras, I would suggest you to report it. For the time being I have added the other options I found to be working.